# How would I listen for real-time updates in express?

Tags: javascript, api, express

I'm making my own API for a database and I need to listen for real-time updates on the server.

I've used firebase before to achieve this using the onSnapshot function.

I was wondering how I could get the same, or at least similar result with express.

The API will be used outside the client-side of the node, so I will be accessing the API from other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) library.

From the website:

> Socket.IO enables real-time, bidirectional and event-based
> communication. It works on every platform, browser or device, focusing
> equally on reliability and speed.